# How to close a stream properly?

Tags: f#, stream, streamreader, streamwriter

I have been assigned a task to write a program that will:

1. Open a file.
2. Read the content.
3. Replace a specific word with another word.
4. Save the changes to the file.

I know for sure that my code can open, read and replace words. The problem occurs when i add the "Save the changes to the file" - part. Here is the code:

```
open System.IO

//Getting the filename, needle and replace-word.
System.Console.WriteLine "What is the name of the file?"
let filename = string (System.Console.ReadLine ())

System.Console.WriteLine "What is your needle?"
let needle = string (System.Console.ReadLine ())

System.Console.WriteLine "What you want your needle replaced with?"
let replace = string (System.Console.ReadLine ())   

//Saves the content of the file
let mutable saveLine = ""   

//Opens a stream to read the file
let reader = File.OpenText filename

//Reads the file, and replaces the needle.
let printFile (reader : System.IO.StreamReader) =
  while not(reader.EndOfStream) do
    let line = reader.ReadLine ()
    let lineReplace = line.Replace(needle,replace)
    saveLine <- saveLine + lineReplace
    printfn "%s" lineReplace

//Opens a stream to write to the file
let readerWrite = File.CreateText(filename)

//Writes to the file
let editFile (readerWrite : System.IO.StreamWriter) =
  File.WriteAllText(filename,saveLine)

printf "%A" (printFile reader)
```

I get the error message "Sharing violation on path...", which makes me believe that the reading stream do not close properly. I have tried playing around with the structure of my code and tried different things for the .NET library, but i always get the same error message. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streams are normally closed by calling [Stream.Close()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close(v=vs.110).aspx) or disposing them.

`System.IO` has methods to read or write complete files from/to arrays of lines. This would shorten the operation to something like this:

```
File.ReadAllLines filePath
|> Array.map (fun line -> line.Replace(needle, replace))
|> fun editedLines -> File.WriteAllLines(filePath, editedLines)
```

What documentation are you using? Have a look at [the MSDN documentation for System.IO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io(v=vs.110).aspx) and the similar MSDN documentations for various things in .NET/the CLR; these answer questions like this one quickly.

Comment: wow, I could never have imagined that this code could be written in 3 lines. I think your code is brilliant - however, I feel like I still need to find the problem with my code. I tried calling Stream.Close(), but i'm still getting the same error message. I even tried changing to File.ReadAllLines (because ReadAllLines closes the file after reading). I think my "writing to file"-code is just wrong. I tried reading "How to: Write Text to a File" on msdn's website, but there were no f# examples. Can you see what is wrong with my code?

Comment: @Hakan I think you should accept Vandroiy's Answer, since it uses ReadAlllines and WriteAllLines, which is the easiest way to solve these types of problems. Regarding your problems, see my post.

Comment: Another comment I couldn't abstain from: see how close this answer follows the problem definition: Line 1: (Open the file) and Read the content, Line 2: Replace the word, Line 3: Write the content. It's indeed beautiful.

Comment: @Hakan I see s952163 has already answered your further question. Glad you like the answers! When reading the MSDN, I'd recommend learning basic C# syntax. It's not very difficult, has similarities to F#'s imperative features, and F# is highly compatible with C# libraries, so it's common to just read the C# documentation and translate to F# for usage. They're using the same runtime environment, so the behavior is identical unless you're using features specific to F#.

Answer (score 1):

I retained most of your original code, although it's not very idiomatic. If you use `use` with disposable resources, .NET will clean up after you. See for example [F# Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/resource-management-the-use-keyword) and [Fun&Profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/let-use-do/), the latter also has a nice section on [Expressions and syntax](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/expressions-and-syntax.html).

If you execute your code, you should get System.IO.IOException:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access
>   the file 'C:\Users\xcs\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\StackOverflow6\ConsoleApplication11\bin\Release\testout.txt'
>   because it is being used by another process.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append,
>   Boolean checkHost)    at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path,
>   Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean
>   checkHost)    at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean
>   append)    at System.IO.File.CreateText(String path)    at
>   Program.op@46(Unit unitVar0) in C:\Users\xcs\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2015\Projects\StackOverflow6\ConsoleApplication11\Program.fs:line 74
>   at Program.main(String[] argv) in C:\Users\xcs\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2015\Projects\StackOverflow6\ConsoleApplication11\Program.fs:line 83

It starts at line 83, which is the call to the function, goes to line 74. Line 74 is the following: `let readerWrite = File.CreateText(filename)`. Nowhere in your code have you closed `reader`. There is also another problem, you're opening a `StreamWriter` with `File.CreateText`. And then you're trying to write to this opened stream with `File.WriteAllText`, which opens the file, writes to it and closes it. So a bunch of IO handles are floating around there...

To quickly fix it consider the following:

```
//Getting the filename, needle and replace-word.
System.Console.WriteLine "What is the name of the file?"
let filename = string (System.Console.ReadLine ())

System.Console.WriteLine "What is your needle?"
let needle = string (System.Console.ReadLine ())

System.Console.WriteLine "What you want your needle replaced with?"
let replace = string (System.Console.ReadLine ())   

//Saves the content of the file


//Opens a stream to read the file
//let reader = File.OpenText filename

//Reads the file, and replaces the needle.
let printFile (filename:string) (needle:string) (replace:string) =
  let mutable saveLine = ""
  use reader = File.OpenText filename //use will ensure that the stream is disposed once its out of scope, i.e. the functions exits
  while not(reader.EndOfStream) do
    let line = reader.ReadLine ()
    let lineReplace = line.Replace(needle,replace)
    saveLine <-  saveLine  + lineReplace + "\r\n" //you will need a newline character
    printfn "%s" lineReplace
  saveLine    


//Writes to the file
let editFile filename saveLine =
    File.WriteAllText(filename,saveLine)   //you don't need a stream here, since File.WriteAllText will open, write, then close the file

let saveLine = printFile filename needle replace //read the file into saveLine
editFile filename saveLine       //write saveLine into the file
```

It does a couple of things:

1. creates the `StreamReader` inside the `printFile`
2. binds it to reader with `use`, not let, to ensure it is closed once we don't need it anymore
3. add a linefeed to the string, since you insist rebuilding a mutable string
4. encapsulates the mutable `saveLine` inside the function
5. passes the needle and replace arguments explicitly
6. returns a new string to be used in 7.
7. gets rid of the `Streamwriter` by using `File.WriteAllText` and also passes in explicitly the filename and the string to write

Comment: Excellent! We have not been introduced to the "use" binding yet, but I can now see how it comes in handy. Thank you.

Comment: Why the use of `string` function in addition to `ReadLine` which already returns a string ?

Comment: @Sehnsucht Good comment! Yes, sir. I know, I just didn't want to cramp the OP's style too much. ;-) I think after this is working it should go onto codereview, but below Vandroiy already compressed it quite a bit.